# Having trouble connecting phpMyAdmin and AppEngine locally

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-platform

I followed [these](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine) instructions to get phpMyAdmin working on AppEngine. But, I can't get it working locally. Here's what I've tried as my `config.inc.php` file:

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'ZZZZZZZZZ';

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

$isGAE = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) &&
         strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false;

/*
* First server
*/
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
if ($isGAE) {
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/cloudsql/XXXXXX:YYYYYY';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
} else {
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
}
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

/*
* Other settings
*/
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 60;
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
```

When I run `dev_appserver.py .` in the directory, it runs and I get a "Not logged in" screen with test@example.com. I check the Administrator box, and then try to enter my local root credentials. However, it tells me "Cannot log in to the MySQL server". When I run `mysql -u root -p` locally, I can log in successfully with the same password.

Any ideas? Any chance the existing tutorial could be extended to talk about connecting to a local mysql instance?

Answer (score 0):

The log in screen you described is for the GAE auth. It simulates logging in into the App not your MySQL server. That screen is used when the app.yaml has a login: required or admin flags set. You need another way to set the uname/pass for your MySQL server.